# uniq -c Equivalent for Groups of Lines of Arbitrary Count

Tags: awk, perl, uniq

I've got a file of ~1-2 million lines that I'm trying to reduce down by counting duplicate groups of lines, preserving order.

`uniq -c` works okay :

```
$ perl -E 'say for (("foo") x 4, ("bar") x 4, "baz", ("foo", "bar", "baz") x 4)' | uniq -c
      4 foo
      4 bar
      1 baz
      1 foo
      1 bar
      1 baz
      1 foo
      1 bar
      1 baz
      1 foo
      1 bar
      1 baz
      1 foo
      1 bar
      1 baz
```

In my use-case (but not in the following foo-bar-baz example), counting **pairs** of lines is ~20% more efficient, and looks like :

```
$ perl -E 'say for (("foo") x 4, ("bar") x 4, "baz", ("foo", "bar", "baz") x 4)' \
  | sed 's/^/__STARTOFSTRINGDELIMITER__/' \
  | paste - - \
  | uniq -c \
  | sed -r 's/__STARTOFSTRINGDELIMITER__//; s/__STARTOFSTRINGDELIMITER__/\n\t/;'
      2 foo
        foo
      2 bar
        bar
      1 baz
        foo
      1 bar
        baz
      1 foo
        bar
      1 baz
        foo
      1 bar
        baz
      1 foo
        bar
      1 baz
```

(That format is acceptable to me.)

How can I reduce duplicate groups of arbitrary numbers of lines (well, keeping a sane buffer count like 2-10 lines) down to a single copy + count of them ?

Following the above example, I would want output similar to :

```
4 foo
4 bar
1 baz
4 foo
  bar
  baz
```

Comment: That's similar to what some compression algorithms do. Maybe some avenue worth exploring.

Comment: The issue seems to be finding the groups of lines. Your output may as well say that the combination of `foo` followed by `bar` occur 5 times.

Comment: @Kusalananda Do you mean `foo` followed by `bar` *4* times ? (The first two sets of four each). You would be correct then, yes, and either output would be acceptable for me (either `foo` x4 then `bar` x4, or (`foo`, `bar`) x4). I assume it would depend on the buffer length - 10 lines of buffer would produce the latter, less than 8 lines of buffer would produce the former. It's not really an issue as you say, just a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have such a huge dataset for benchmarking. Give this a try:

```
$ perl -E 'say for (("foo") x 4, ("bar") x 4, "baz", ("foo", "bar", "baz") x 4)' | awk 'NR == 1 {word=$0; count=1; next} $0 != word {print count,word; word=$0; count=1; next} { count++ } END { print count,word }'
4 foo
4 bar
1 baz
1 foo
1 bar
1 baz
1 foo
1 bar
1 baz
1 foo
1 bar
1 baz
1 foo
1 bar
1 baz
```

Using `mawk` instead of `awk` may improve performance.

Comment: Can this be adapted to work with multi-word lines ? 
`echo -e 'a b c \n a b c \n a b c' | awk 'NR == 1 {word=$1; count=1; next} $1 != word {print count,word; word=$1; count=1; next} { count++ } END { print count,word }'`
for example only counts `a`. 
Sorry that it wasn't clear in my original question that my actual lines are multi-word with non-alphanumeric characters too.

Comment: Just replace the `$1` with `$0` to compare whole lines. I've edited my answer.